# How do I increase maximum tokenization length in Google Colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I have a list with over 2,000 coordinates and Google Colab says "Tokenization is skipped for long lines for performance reasons.  This can be configured via editor.maxTokenizationLineLength()".  I can tell the elements in the list are not being tokenized because the integers are no longer green but white font.

I am not sure where I can read more about this function and what parameters it requires.  I was not able to find a setting for it either.

I tried running editor.maxTokenizationLineLength(20000) in a cell and it throws an error.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.